# Who says צִוָּה vs. צַוֵּה at a b'ris?

Tags: minhag, blessing, brit-milah, nuschaot, communities

The passage "על כן בשכר זאת קל חי חלקנו צורנו צוה להציל ידידות שארנו משחת" is part of one of the blessings recited at a *b'ris mila*. *Pische S'shuva* (*Yore Dea* 265:4) cites a difference of opinion as to whether the word "צִוָּה / *tziva* / commanded"<sup>[1]</sup> or "צַוֵּה / *tzave* / command"<sup>[2]</sup> appears in it, and concludes that either is okay. (The commentaries he quotes discuss why one word might be better than the other.) In practice, which communities recite each?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> That is, "therefore, in this merit, the living God… commanded to save…".
<sup>[2]</sup> That is, "therefore, in this merit, O living God… command to save…".

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48924&hilite=45981147-c0d2-4bad-aecf-04f8a324449b&st=+%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94+%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%9C+%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA+%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%95